# Monstera with tiny white flecks (spores?), large brown spots, small white dots

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, leaves, insects, fungus

I thought this might be under-watering but have just noticed these small white flecks (first photo) - they can be brushed off but are covering the entire plant, even the healthy leaves and stems. They seem too small to be scale insects and I can’t see any spider mites. There are dark brown patches on a lot of the leaves, and one of the stems has started turning brown too (second photo). There are also small (approx 0.5 mm) brown/white dots that are discolourations of the leaf itself (third photo). I've had this monstera for around three years and it's been completely fine until the last few weeks.

My flatmates monstera has had a similar issue. It has deteriorated over a few months and is now completely covered in large brown patches. I'm not sure if it also had the white flecks/small dots. Wondering if could be a bug that has spread.

Very grateful for any help!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you share more details about the spots? Do they move, or jump?

Comment: They seem like some sort of mite to me, I'd say wash the monstera leaves carefully under water to remove them!

Answer (score 1):

They're thrips, and are very contagious and persistent. There are several ways to treat them, you could google to see one that suits you. Best of luck, definitely isolate the sick plants as they spread. Best of luck!

Comment: I agree that these are thrips. They are very very aggressive and hard to get rid of. The plant should be treated frequently even if there is no sign of thrips anymore. Also when mature these little devils can fly, be aware of that.